# Get the maximum time of a date

Tags: c#

How can I get the maximum time of a DateTime value selected from datetimepicker?
For example '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

Comment: Daylight Saving Time.  Leap seconds.

Comment: You just add a day to it, then subtract a second. Depends what you mean by last time though, you might want a second, a minute, or an hour. Pretty common when you want it for an `EndDate` to compare with, when you don't want `<` beginning of the day, but end of it.

Comment: @Inuyasha not true: with DateTime, there is no such thing as a leap second.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx ("Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks that would be added by leap seconds).")

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`myDateTime.AddDays(1).Date.AddSeconds(-1)`

**Update**
As per comments by @RenatoGama on the question:

One possible other answer specific to end date scenarios is `myDateTime.Date.AddDays(1)`. which gets you the next day to end date, use `<` instead of `<=` (as in `dateTocheck < endDate.Date.AddDays(1)`).

Sample:

```
'08/21/2011 13:03:59' -> .AddDays(1)     -> '08/22/2011 13:03:59' 

'08/22/2011 13:03:59' -> .Date           -> '08/22/2011 00:00:00'  

'08/22/2011 00:00:00' -> .AddSeconds(-1) -> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'
// OR
'08/22/2011 00:00:00' -> .AddTicks(-1)   -> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'
// Note: A tick is the smallest unit for time difference that DateTime can detect
// So, technically more accurate answer than using seconds -- Thanks @aron
```

Note: AFAIK, '08/22/2011' == '08/22/2011 00:00:00'

Comment: That's why I use the `Date` property, which sets the time part to zeros.

Comment: @RenatoGama `'08/21/2011 13:03:59'.AddDays(1)` -> '08/22/2011 13:03:59' -> `.Date` -> '08/22/2011' -> `.AddSeconds(-1)` -> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

Comment: @phoog, think its '08/21/2011 13:03:59'.AddDays(1) -> '08/22/2011 13:03:59' -> .Date -> '08/22/2011 00:00:00' -> .AddSeconds(-1) -> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

Comment: @RenatoGama AFAIK, '08/22/2011' == '08/22/2011 00:00:00'.

Comment: I think you incorrectly spelt `AddTicks` as `AddSeconds`. This is unfortunate, as that also compiles.

Comment: LOL. Good one! Fixed :)

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2017, 1, 13);
//d= 13/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
d = d.Add(DateTime.MaxValue.TimeOfDay);
//d= 13/1/2017 11:59:59 PM
```

Answer (score 3):

The **minimun** value

> '08/21/2011 00:00:00'

The **maximun** value

> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

**Usage:**

```
   var firstDate = dtpFrom.Value.Date; //  0:00:00
   var secondDate =  dtpTo.Value.Date.AddSeconds(86400 - 1); //23:59:59 - 86400 is 24 hours
   var list = Services.GetListForFilter(firstDate, secondDate);
```